# How do I see if NSTimers are stacking and how to prevent it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

Im making an iphone game that uses NStimer for movement. I found out that there is a bug that makes the timers stack some times, but i havnt found out what causes is. Is there any way to see how many timers are allocated and is there any way to prevent it by doing something like this:

```
If(myTimer.numberOfAllocatedTimers == 0) {
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateme) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: You need to use `==`, not `=` to see if the number of timers is zero.

Comment: well myTimer.numberofAllocatedTimers was just something i wrote to show you what i mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to unschedule NSTimer in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334552/how-to-unschedule-nstimer-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// use this to start timer
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(doSthing) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

// use this to stop timer
if (myTimer) {
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more context on where this code is being used would be helpful.

However, I'll try to explain why it's happening anyway.

Every time you use [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...], a *new* timer is created, and will start repeating. If your code creates a timer inside the callback method, see example below, you'll stack timers.

```
- (void)updateme {
    if ([NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateme) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]) {
    // This creates stacked timers!
    }
}
```

Here's how you should do it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
... 
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateme:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
...
- (void)updateme:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (timer == self.myTimer) {
        // Do something because the timers are equal
    }
}
```